# How to perform validation in python when import data by using np.genfromtxt?

Tags: python

I am trying to import a csv file that the format of the first column should be integer and that of the second column should be float. I want to write a function to import this csv file and detect if the data format in each column is correct.
My current idea is like below, but I don't know how to make the data set the data type according to the value of the data.

```
csvfile = 'data.csv'
def read_input_file(csvfile):
   data = np.genfromtxt(csvfile, skip_header=1, delimiter=',')
   if not data[:,0].dtype == 'int64':
       print('wrong')
   elif not data[:,1].dtype == 'float64':
       print('wrong')
   else:
       return data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading in numbers from a csv with np.genfromtxt, you will find that all numbers are interpreted as floats.

```
print(data.dtype)
print(data[:,0].dtype)
print(data[:,1].dtype)
```

Outputs

```
float64
float64
float64
```

This is the default behavior of np.genfromtxt, as is documented [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html).
The default `<class 'float'>` dtype can be overridden by calling

```
np.genfromtxt(csvfile, ..., dtype=None)
```

As the documentation states, the datatype will be determined by the contents of each column, individually.
This means, that the dtype of `data` will in your case now show.

```
[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<f8')]
```

These are 64 bit integers and 64 bit floats, as shown by

```
print(np.dtype('<i8').name)
print(np.dtype('<f8').name)
>>>int64
>>>float64
```

You can access the columns with different datatypes by using their name: Ex. `data['f0']` and `data['f1']`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, I had tried to set the parameter dtype = None. However, the imported data changes from two columns to one column. And if I run
```
data[:,0].dtype
```
There would be an error: IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: Yes that is true. Instead of a single numpy array with a mixed datatypes, numpy returns a list of tuples. Because of this, fields are now accessed by name, not column number. I added this to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can data accessed in this way be changed? I ran ‘data[np.where(data['f0'] == 1)]['f1']+=1’, but nothing happened.